# how to make an input text enabled/desabled depending on the choice of selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this table:
[image]

my problem is that I want to if I check the checkbox of selected row it will enabled/desabled the "Montant" input,this is my try but it never works
I get all the rows activated!!

```
    <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>

                                    <th >
                                      <input type="checkbox" />
                                    </th>
                                    <th>Montant</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody ng-model="finalOperationsList">
                                <tr ng-repeat="item in finalOperationsList track by $index ">
                                    <td class="TableHeaderalignment"><input type="checkbox" 
                                        ng-model="finalOperationsList[$index].checked" ng-change="changeMontantLBL($index)"/></td>
                                    <td class="TableHeaderalignment">
                                       <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{item.montant}}" ng-disabled="montantBL" />
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

and this is function in Controller:

```
 $scope.changeMontantLBL =function($index){

                      if(true){
                          $scope.montantBL = false;
                      }
                      else{
                          $scope.montantBL = true; 
                      }
                  }
```

so please how can I correct my code to make the input "Montant" enabled/desabled depending on the choice of selected row checkbox
thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly consume the value of "`finalOperationsList[$index].checked`" in the `ng-disabled` of the input textbox, and remove the `ng-change` and `scope.montantBL` altogether.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in finalOperationsList track by $index ">
    <td class="TableHeaderalignment"><input type="checkbox" 
        ng-model="finalOperationsList[$index].checked"/></td>
    <td class="TableHeaderalignment">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{item.montant}}" ng-disabled="finalOperationsList[$index].checked" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

It is also worth to note that you might have misused `value="{{item.montant}}"` and should use `ng-model="item.montant"` instead. You can also simplify your code for that row to:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in finalOperationsList track by $index ">
    <td class="TableHeaderalignment">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked"/></td>
    <td class="TableHeaderalignment">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="item.montant" ng-disabled="item.checked"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the bound ng-model (answers[item.questID]) value itself in your ng-change method to detect if it has been checked or not.

Example:-

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="answers[item.questID]" ng-change="stateChanged(item.questID)" /> <!-- Pass the specific id -->
```

and

```
$scope.stateChanged = function (qId) {
 if($scope.answers[qId]){ //If it is checked
    alert('enable or disable input');
 }
```

}